# C# callback on new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

i am having trouble creating a callback on a newly started thread.

I have 2 classes, an API, and the Form.cs. I start a thread running a method in API, from Form.cs, i want to notify a method in Form.cs from inside the method in API.

I am familiar with delegation in Obj-C, but not in C#.

I only included the relevant code.

```
public partial class Main: Form
{

    private Api Connect = new Api();

    private void StartStopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //new thread
        Thread ThreadConnect = new Thread(Connect.startAttemptingWithUsername);
        ThreadConnect.Start();
    }

    public void AttemptingWithPasswordMessage(string password)
    {
        // i want to notify this method from the API
    }
}

class Api : UserAgent
{
    public void startAttemptingWithUsername()
    {
        _shouldStop = false;
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(username);
            // How would i notify AttemptingWithPasswordMessage from here?
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is API object instantiated?

Comment: Shouldn't startAttemptingWithUsername be static? Else you have to create a Api object first.

Comment: Included it in the code

Comment: Why the downvote, elaboration would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide an event to your other class, and fire that event whenever it is relevant based on the processing:

```
class Api : UserAgent
{
    public event Action<string> SomeEvent;//TODO give better name
    public void startAttemptingWithUsername()
    {
        _shouldStop = false;
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(username);
            var handler = SomeEvent;
            if (handler != null)
                handler("asdf");
            // How would i notify AttemptingWithPasswordMessage from here?
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Then add a handler for that event: (And marshal back to the UI thread)

```
private void StartStopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //new thread
    Thread ThreadConnect = new Thread(Connect.startAttemptingWithUsername);
    ThreadConnect.Start();
    Connect.SomeEvent += (data) => Invoke(
        new Action(()=>AttemptingWithPasswordMessage(data)));
}
```