# How do I update the variable from another thread in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

My process is when button click create a background thread to do some process. After the process done will update the variable to true. However, I do the update inside the thread, but in main thread no update.

```
public partial class frm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public bool iscomplete = false;

    Worker workerObject = new Worker();
    
    protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(PrintFunction);
        t1.IsBackground = true;
        t1.Start();
        t1.Name = "PrintThread";
    }
    
    public void PrintFunction()
    {
        //Do process and update iscomplete to true
        workerObject.RequestStop();
        t1.Join();
    }

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                if (workerObject.isComplete == true)
                {

                    GetData();
                    RadGrid1.Rebind();

                }

        }
}

public class Worker
{

    public void RequestStop()
    {
        _isComplete = true;
    }
    // Keyword volatile is used as a hint to the compiler that this data
    // member is accessed by multiple threads.
    private volatile bool _isComplete;
    public bool isComplete
    {
        get
        {
            return _isComplete;
        }
        set
        {
            _isComplete = value;
        }
    }
}
```

How to update the variable after the thread process done?

Comment: You should consider callback mechanism instead of this background thread approach.

Comment: "but in main thread no update" - what main thread? web apps don't have a "main thread" as such; if this is a web request, the original request is probably *long gone* by the time that comes back, unless you're blocking somewhere. How are you testing this? if you're doing a `while (!isComplete)` loop: yeah, don't do that - in fact, you *almost certainly* shouldn't be creating a `Thread` *at all* in a web application (threads are expensive; perhaps consider the thread-pool)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile):

```
private volatile bool _isComplete;
public bool isComplete
{
    get
    {
        return _isComplete;
    }
    set
    {
        _isComplete = value;
    }
}
```

You can also create a [callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307575/c-sharp-callback-on-new-thread).

Pitfall: As Marc Gravell pointed out in the comment section of the question, the thread you consider to be main might be already inexistent at the point your second thread is updating the variable. You will need to be aware of that. If that's a problem, then you may need to synchronize the threads by joining the second thread to the "main" thread, for example.

Comment: Hi @Lajos Arpad , I already updated my question based on your suggested idea. However, I still unable to get the updated value.

Comment: @THG you might be referring to it prior its change. Have you tried to call Join on the thread?

Comment: Hi @Lajos Arpad, Yes I try it. It is same. My process is like when button click it will start the timer event. The timer event will check the variable (iscomplete). This variable will be update to true when the thread is completed.